# Spring Hibernate - difference between CrudRepository and SessionFactory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am looking into persisting my model using Hibernate. I seem to find two approaches to do this.

The first one is using `SessionFactory`, for example:

```
public Collection loadProductsByCategory(String category) {
        return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("from test.Product product where product.category=?")
                .setParameter(0, category)
                .list();
    }
```

The other one uses an annotated subclass/interface extending `CrudRepository`:

```
@Transactional
public interface UserDao extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
  public User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

Also instead of `@Transactional` sometimes I see a `@Repository` annotation. What is the difference there?

I have not found an answer to "when would/should I use the former or latter approach", so could I get an explanation?

Comment: [`SessionFactory`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html), [`CrudRepository`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html), [`@Transactional`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html), [`@Repository`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merely you can find description for these annotations on the Spring docs site.

Shortly, to answer your questions the difference between them is they are used for different purposes.

- [`@Transactional`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) is used to demarcate code involved into transaction. It's placed on classes and methods.
- [`@Repository`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html) is used to define a Spring bean that support transactions, it can be used in DI as well.

They can be used both on the same class.