# Difference between Hibernate SessionFactory and CrudRepository

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have seen many examples and didn't understand the context when should I use SessionFactory or when should I opt for CrudRepository.

I found this [Spring Hibernate - difference between CrudRepository and SessionFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36234206/spring-hibernate-difference-between-crudrepository-and-sessionfactory) in stackoverflow. But it answered difference between annotations used on CrudRepository.

But my question is regarding when to use which method among CrudRepository and SessionFactory or whether both are same.

Comment: did you google it first ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36234206/spring-hibernate-difference-between-crudrepository-and-sessionfactory/36234350#36234350

Comment: @want2learn I have already mentioned that in my question. Please read the question carefully.